# What's about Rational::compatible and Complex::compatible?

Tags: ruby

can anybody explain the existence of (sub)classes mentioned in the
subject ?

- documentation is missing

  http://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational/compatible.html

  http://ruby-doc.org/core/Complex/compatible.html
- identifier break class/constant naming rule. It starts with lowercase but should start with an uppercase.
- are inaccessible by standard ways although their existence is
  registered:

_

```
Rational::constants false
# [:compatible]

Rational::compatible
# NoMethodError: undefined method 'compatible' for Rational:Class

Rational::const_get 'compatible'
# NameError: wrong constant name compatible
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this class exists for Marshal backwards-compatibility with older versions of Ruby. In other words, it makes it so `Marshal.load` in one version of Ruby can load Complex and Rational objects that were marshaled in an older version of Ruby.

You can see where the Rational::compatible class is defined on the second line here ([line 2,446 in `rational.c`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/rational.c#2546)):

```c
rb_define_private_method(rb_cRational, "marshal_dump", nurat_marshal_dump, 0);
compat = rb_define_class_under(rb_cRational, "compatible", rb_cObject);
rb_define_private_method(compat, "marshal_load", nurat_marshal_load, 1);
rb_marshal_define_compat(rb_cRational, compat, nurat_dumper, nurat_loader);
```

My C is lousy, but to me it looks like these four lines do the following, respectively:

1. Defines the `Rational#marshal_dump` private method as a pointer to the C function `nurat_marshal_load`.
2. Defines the `compatible` class under the `Rational` class (`rb_cRational`). I think the third argument, `rb_cObject` is the superclass.
3. Defines `Rational#marshal_load` as the C function `nurat_marshal_dump`.
4. This is the interesting one: It calls `rb_marshal_define_compat` with four arguments: the Rational class (`rb_cRational`); the Rational::compatible class (`compat`) just defined; and `nurat_dumper` and `nurat_loader`.

Starting at [line 1,629](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/rational.c#1630) in the same file you can see where `nurat_dumper` and `nurat_loader` (along with `nurat_marshal_dump` and `nurat_marshal_load`) are defined. Using the magic of `git blame` we can see exactly when `nurat_dumper` and `nurat_loader` were defined: July 25, 2012 in Subversion commit [#36538](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/003c45f9cd570335b7360241724b6967a8ab014a#diff-1b95f88442a0105e3ea80d1232646f19R1593). Here's the commit message:

> #### complex.c, rational.c: compatible marshal loader
>
> - `complex.c`, `rational.c`: compatible marshal loader for compatibilities with 1.8.  [ruby-core:45775] [Bug #6625]

Now we're getting somewhere! [Bug #6625](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6625) is this one:

> #### broken Marshal compatibilities on Complex and Rational
>
> Complex and Rational dumped by 1.8 or earlier cannot be loaded by trunk.

It goes on to describe a test case and includes the patch seen in the above commit.

So what, perhaps you're wondering, is `rb_marshal_define_compat`? You can see it [defined in `marshal.c`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/marshal.c#113). Like I said, my C is lousy, but I think what it does is put its arguments—`newclass` (i.e. Rational), `oldclass` (Rational::compatible), `dumper` and `loader`—into a [`marshal_compat_t` struct](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/marshal.c#091) and inserts that into `compat_allocator_tbl`. Later on, when you try to `Marshal.dump` or `Marshal.load` an object it will look in that table to see if a compatibility class exists for it and use its "dumper" or "loader" if necessary.

As for why Rational::compatible isn't named with a capital letter and isn't accessible by normal means, I can only guess that this is by design so that it can only be accessed internally by Ruby.

You can, however, get a reference to the class using ObjectSpace, although you can't do much with it:

```
compatible = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).find do |o|
  o.name == "Rational::compatible"
end

p compatible
# => Rational::compatible

p compatible.instance_methods(false)
# => []

p compatible.private_instance_methods(false)
# => [:marshal_load]
```

Comment: Wow, this answer is more comprehensive then I did expected and really answers the question. Thanks.